# Google prettify language for boolean queries

Tags: javascript, lucene, syntax-highlighting, google-code-prettify

I am trying to "pretty print" boolean queries using [google-code-prettify](http://code.google.com/p/google-code-prettify/). Specifially queries that will be parsed by the StandardQueryParser in lucene.

So far I have been playing around, trying to define a new language definition by modifying the existing lang-sql.js file. Unfortunately I cannot find any documentation to help me in this process, and I'm terrible at regular expressions, so it's not going that well.

I am therefore wondering if anyone can help me out with the following:

1. Are there any pre-existing language definitions for boolean and/or lucene queries?
2. If not, is there any documentation or any resources on the web that can help me write custom language definitions for google-code-prettify?
3. Are there any other alternatives to google-code-prettify that supports these types of boolean queries out of the box?

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: are you asking what the lucene query syntax is? if so, look no further than http://lucene.apache.org/core/4_9_0/queryparser/org/apache/lucene/queryparser/classic/package-summary.html

Comment: It's not really what I am after at the current time, although it will certainly help if I ever get the hang of writing the language definitions for code-prettify. Thanks =)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up using Hightlight.js instead of google-code-prettify. I was able to make a simple syntax for highlighting Lucene queries in a way that fits my requirements.

Hightlight.js has [decent development documentation](http://highlightjs.readthedocs.org/en/latest/language-guide.html), and the source code, cloned from [git repository](https://github.com/isagalaev/highlight.js), comes with build script (in python) and easy to use tools for testing styles and language  definitions.